# what's wrong with this for loop? weird error

Tags: java, for-loop

I was learning about for loops and whenever I do this loop

```
String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};
        for (int k = fruits.length;k > 0; k--) {
            System.out.println(fruits[k]);
}
```

and I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:439)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

and I don't want to do a for each loop.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're starting at the length of the array, `int k = fruits.length` -- that's beyond what the array allows since arrays are 0-based and go from 0 to length - 1. More importantly, you will want to learn to use and practice using your debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indexes for a Java array start at 0.  So if there are 3 things in the array, their indexes are 0, 1 and 2.

You've set up your loop so that it starts at `k = 3`, and on subsequent iterations (if it reached them), it would have `k = 2` then `k = 1`.

But these don't match the indexes in the array.  In particular, when `k = 3`, there's no matching entry in the array, which is what's making your program crash.

You need to change the way your loop is set up, so that it iterates `k = 2`, then `k = 1`, then `k = 0`.  May I suggest the following change?

```
for (int k = fruits.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
```

Everything else can stay the same.